# Finding the index of the maximum number in a python matrix which includes strings

Tags: python, list, numpy, matrix

I understand that

```
np.argmax(np.max(x, axis=1))
```

returns the index of the row that contains the maximum value and

```
np.argmax(np.max(x, axis=0))
```

returns the index of the row that contains the maximum value.

But what if the matrix contained strings? How can I change the code so that it still finds the index of the largest value?

Also (if there's no way to do what I previously asked for), can I change the code so that the operation is only carried out on a sub-section of the matrix, for instance, on the bottom right '2x2' sub-matrix in this example:

```
array = [['D','F,'J'],
['K',3,4],
['B',3,1]]

[[3,4],
[3,1]]
```

Comment: What's the `largest value`?  How does `K` or `J` compare to 3 or 4?

Comment: The largest value is the largest number, in this case, it will be 4. J and K are just random strings in the matrix.

Comment: With some strings, then either the whole array is strings, or it's object dtype.  Check the `dtype`.  You might need to replace the strings with some innocuous value (that won't be min or max), and then do the `arg...`.  Watch the `dtype`.

Comment: @hpaulj do you know how I could slice the Matrix to get the sub-matrix I specified?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try first converting the column to type dtype? If you take the min/max of a dtype column, it should use string values for the minimum/maximum.

Answer (score 0):

Although not efficient, this could be one way to find index of the maximum number in the original matrix by using slices:

```
newmax=0
newmaxrow=0
newmaxcolumn=0

for row in [array[i][1:] for i in range(1,2)]:
    for num in row:
        if num>newmax:
            newmax=num
            newmaxcolumn=row.index(newmax)+1
            newmaxrow=[array[i][1:] for i in range(1,2)].index(row)+1
```

Note: this method would not work if the lagest number lies within row 0 or column 0.